# Chrome NET::err_cert_common_name_invalid error while creating my own certificate using Python's cryptography module

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, openssl, python-cryptography

I am creating a certificate signed by own self-signed root authority. This is used to serve a domain hosted as a local app, which is mapped to a localhost address by `/etc/hosts` file. When the website is requested inside the browser my local app (written in `flask`) serves the app content while supplying the self-signed certificates I created for the domain. I have code written in `Python`'s `Cryptography` module, and it follows these basic steps:

a) create a self-signed root authority with its own `.CRT` and `.KEY`

b) generate a `CSR` corresponding to my domain name after generating a separate private key for it

c) have my certificate authority sign the `CSR` and generate the certificate.

```
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes, serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import load_der_private_key
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.x509.oid import NameOID
import datetime
import uuid
import os
import sys
import subprocess

def generate_root_CA():
    """
    a) generate rootCA key
    b) generate rootCA crt
    """

    ##generating root key

    root_private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(
    public_exponent=65537,
    key_size=2048,
    backend=default_backend())


    ##self-sign and generate the root certificate

    root_public_key = root_private_key.public_key()
    builder = x509.CertificateBuilder()
    builder = builder.subject_name(x509.Name([
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COMMON_NAME, u'Test CA'),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.ORGANIZATION_NAME, u'Org'),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.ORGANIZATIONAL_UNIT_NAME, u'Testing unit'),
    ]))

    builder = builder.issuer_name(x509.Name([
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COMMON_NAME, u'Test CA'),
    ]))
    builder = builder.not_valid_before(datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1))
    builder = builder.not_valid_after(datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 31))
    builder = builder.serial_number(int(uuid.uuid4()))
    builder = builder.public_key(root_public_key)
    builder = builder.add_extension(
    x509.BasicConstraints(ca=True, path_length=None), critical=True,)

    root_certificate = builder.sign(
        private_key=root_private_key, algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
        backend=default_backend()
    )


    ##write to disk

    with open("rootCA.key", "wb") as f:
        f.write(root_private_key.private_bytes(
            encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
            format=serialization.PrivateFormat.TraditionalOpenSSL,
            encryption_algorithm=serialization.BestAvailableEncryption(b"passphrase")
        ))

    with open("rootCA.crt", "wb") as f:
        f.write(root_certificate.public_bytes(
            encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
        ))

    return root_private_key, root_certificate

def generate_key():
    """
    a) generate key for the certificate being created
    """
    key = rsa.generate_private_key(
        public_exponent=65537,
        key_size=2048,
        backend=default_backend()
    )

    return key

def generate_csr(key, domain_name):
    """
    generate csr for the client certificate
    """
    csr = x509.CertificateSigningRequestBuilder().subject_name(x509.Name([
    # Provide various details about who we are.
        x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COUNTRY_NAME, u"US"),
        x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.STATE_OR_PROVINCE_NAME, u"MA"),
        x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.LOCALITY_NAME, u"Boston"),
        x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.ORGANIZATION_NAME, u"Org"),
        x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COMMON_NAME, domain_name),
    ])).add_extension(
        x509.SubjectAlternativeName([
        x509.DNSName(domain_name),
        x509.DNSName(u"www." + domain_name),
    ]),
    critical=False,

    # Sign the CSR with our private key.
    ).sign(key, hashes.SHA256(), default_backend())

    # Write our CSR out to disk.
    with open(domain_name + ".csr", "wb") as f:
        f.write(csr.public_bytes(serialization.Encoding.PEM))

    return csr

def sign_certificate_request(csr, rootkey, rootcrt, client_key, domain_name):
    """
    generate the certificate based on the csr created
    """


    crt = x509.CertificateBuilder().subject_name(
        csr.subject
    ).issuer_name(
        rootcrt.subject
    ).public_key(
        csr.public_key()
    ).serial_number(
        uuid.uuid4().int  # pylint: disable=no-member
    ).not_valid_before(
        datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    ).not_valid_after(
        datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=2)
    ).add_extension(
        extension=x509.KeyUsage(
            digital_signature=True, key_encipherment=True, content_commitment=True,
            data_encipherment=False, key_agreement=False, encipher_only=False, decipher_only=False, key_cert_sign=False, crl_sign=False
        ),
        critical=True
    ).add_extension(
        extension=x509.BasicConstraints(ca=False, path_length=None),
        critical=True
    ).add_extension(
        extension=x509.AuthorityKeyIdentifier.from_issuer_public_key(rootkey.public_key()),
        critical=False
    ).sign(
        private_key=rootkey,
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
        backend=default_backend()
    )

    with open(domain_name + ".crt", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(crt.public_bytes(encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM)) 



def main():

    domain_name = "domain.org"
    root_key, root_crt = generate_root_CA()
    domain_key = generate_key()
    csr = generate_csr(domain_key, domain_name)
    sign_certificate_request(csr, root_key, root_crt, domain_key, domain_name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

In Chrome, however I am getting the 'ERR: CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID' error. Reading up online, it seems that for this to go away, one needs to specify ones domain name within the `Subject Alternative Field` inside the CSR request, and it has to match the `Common Name`. That, however, is being already done inside the code (as can be seen in the `generate_csr` function). Additionally, I've imported the root certificate inside Chrome's root store. Could anyone help what could be the error over here?

Answer (score 1):

Extensions in the CSR are not automatically copied into the certificate. You'll need to explicitly call `add_extension` with the `SubjectAlternativeName` object again in `sign_certificate_request`.